# Should custom UIInputView be a singleton?

Tags: ios, keyboard

If I am writing a custom `UIInputView`, shouldn't the view be a singleton...especially if it's expensive to create?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinputview

Kindly note that I am not talking about a `UIInputViewController` that can be used globally in any app; my view will be restricted to my own app.

Any pitfalls with a singleton in this case? The view will communicate key taps with a typical delegate pattern interface.

One pitfall I can see is that `UITextField` ands `UITextView` appear to hold a strong reference to the `inputView` property. This may cause the singleton to never be deallocated.

Comment: Will you use this view in more than one view controller? Also why is it expensive to create, exactly? That seems like a bad smell.

Comment: Yes, it will be used in multiple view controllers. It's just a custom keyboard that presents keyboard buttons in a more user-friendly way for my app. Mine is not expensive to create, per se, but I could envision some fancy custom keyboard with lots of graphics.

Comment: But even lots of graphics would not necessarily be expensive to create. Whereas, views can be expensive to maintain. It seems to me that you may be guilty of premature optimization. If you’re not having a problem, stop spending time and energy solving the problem you’re not having.